# Secure Solr to server Document to specific website only

Tags: security, solr, lucene

I am using `solr 4.10.3`.

I have a website that provides some search via communication with `solr`. Now `solr` port is open and anyone can read data from `solr`. But I do not want to allow this.

I want just to serve my own website only and website should read `solr` data and it should not do any type of updating. How I can achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry like deny all IP and allow only one which is of your application.

```
# Deny access to everyone, except those listed here:
<Files *>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from .*example\.com.*
</Files>
```